# Where can I find the initial commands shown when you have an empty repository, after you actual populate a repository?

Tags: gitlab

[image]

These shortcuts are great and I'm a newbie and I am trying to help other newbies.

Is there a way to access these same entries after the repository actually has data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those commands are not specific to GitLab, they are all **regular Git commands** for configuring your Git identity, cloning a new repo, making your first commits, and pushing them to the remote repo. So, you can basically find them in most "getting started with Git" documentations. It's just summarized on that page, which is great for a quickstart, but bad if you are going to keep it as a reference because **there are no explanations**.

GitLab has their own "getting started with Git" documentation, available either from the public docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/) or the docs from the help links if you are running your own community edition instance locally.

On the public one, it's here: [Start using Git on the command line](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html):

> This guide will help you get started with Git through the command line and can be your reference for Git commands in the future. If you’re only looking for a quick reference of Git commands, you can download the [GitLab Git Cheat Sheet](https://about.gitlab.com/images/press/git-cheat-sheet.pdf).

All the commands can be found on this page, **WITH explanations** this time, which IMHO is better than having a bare list of commands.

For the **Git global setup**:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#configure-git

> In your shell, add your user name:
>
> ```
> git config --global user.name "your_username"
> ```
>
> And your email address:
>
> ```
> git config --global user.email "your_email_address@example.com"
> ```

For the **Create a new repository**:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#clone-a-repository

> **Clone via SSH**
> To clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git via SSH:
>
> ```
> git clone git@gitlab.com:gitlab-org/gitlab.git
> ```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#add-and-commit-local-changes

> Add and commit local changes
> You’ll see any local changes in red when you type git status. These changes may be new, modified, or deleted files/folders. Use git add to first stage (prepare) a local file/folder for committing. Then use git commit to commit (save) the staged files:
>
> ```
> git add <file-name OR folder-name>
> git commit -m "COMMENT TO DESCRIBE THE INTENTION OF THE COMMIT"
> ```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#send-changes-to-gitlabcom

> To push all local commits (saved changes) to the remote repository:
>
> ```
> git push <remote> <name-of-branch>
> ```

As with anything related to Git, if you're trying to learn about Git, it is always best to consult the [Git Pro Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2). It has its own [Git Basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) section, also **WITH detailed explanations**.

Comment: Thank you that helps... as I'm so new to this.